# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<dynamic>>'

Tags: arrays, flutter, dictionary, fetch

I am facing a problem with my code. I get the error :

type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List>'

here's how I tried

```
 Map<String, List> mySelectedEvents = {};

 loadPreviousEvents() async {
    var url = 'http://xxxxxxxx/getEvents.php';
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = json.decode(res.body);

    mySelectedEvents = response
        .fold({}, (previousValue, element) {
          Map val = previousValue as Map;
          String date = element['date'];
          if (!val.containsKey(date)) {
            val[date] = [];
          }
          element.remove('date');
          val[date]?.add(element);
          return val;
        })
        .entries
        .map((e) => {e.key: e.value})
        .toList();
    print(mySelectedEvents);
    return mySelectedEvents;
  }
```

by running the function I would like to have a MAP like this

```
loadPreviousEvents() {
    mySelectedEvents = {
      "2022-09-13": [
        {"eventDescp": "11", "eventTitle": "111"},
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-30": [
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-20": [
        {"eventTitle": "ss", "eventDescp": "ss"}
      ]
    };
  }
```

Comment: can i see your response?

Comment: Try to print the type/format of "response" and add it here? We don't know what the URL will return

Comment: print response : [{date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: azerty, eventTitle: azertyui}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 11, eventTitle: AZE}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 22, eventTitle: 4556}, {date: 2022-09-20, eventDescp: 77, eventTitle: HHJ}, {date: 2022-09-17, eventDescp: 44, eventTitle: BYYY}]